# C# in Rider: Cannot resolve symbol "System"

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core, mono, rider

I have school assignment where I have to implement specific algorithm to v# template.
The template is c# project:

```
GamePhysics2023/
├── GamePhysics.csproj
├── GamePhysics.sln
└── Program.cs
```

GamePhysics.csproj:

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Program.cs:

```cs
using System;

namespace GamePhysics {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var originalDistance = 1.5.Meters();
            var deltaDistance = 2.Meters();
            var distance = originalDistance + deltaDistance;
            Console.WriteLine($"Moving {deltaDistance} after {originalDistance} travelled equals total distance of {distance}");

            var time = 3.Seconds();
            var speed = distance / time;
            Console.WriteLine($"Distance of {distance} travelled in {time} equals speed of {speed}");
            
            speed *= 2;
            Console.WriteLine($"Doubled speed: {speed}");
            
            speed = 3.5.MeterPerSeconds();
            Console.WriteLine($"New speed: {speed}");
            
            // !!! Uncommenting following line must produce Error: Operator '*=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'MeterPerSecond' and 'Meter'
            // speed *= distance;
            // !!! Uncommenting following line must produce Error: Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Meter' and 'Second'
            // distance += time;
        }
    }
}
```

But when I open it in Rider I get these errors:

[image]

What should I do to make rider work ?
Thank you for help

PS: I am on linux

---

Edit:

`dotnet --version` returns `5.0.408`

Comment: What does `dotnet --version` return?

Comment: What is the content of the `Program.cs` file?

Comment: @beautifulcoder I have edited question to answers your question

Comment: @VladDX and same for you

Comment: @JanČerný, what if you run `dotnet --list-sdks`?

Comment: @JanČerný, `<TargetFramework>` doesn't match `dotnet --version`

Comment: `net7.0` indicates this is a .NET 7 project, so you cannot work on it without .NET 7 SDK, https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0 Clearly you only got .NET 5.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is your target framework in the csproj file. Change it to the framework you have installed.

```xml
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```